# Upgraded to Windows 10, forgot to backup EFS key for encrypted files

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions, windows-10-upgrade, efs

I recently upgraded to Windows 10.

I realized I forgot to backup my EFS key so no I can't access my encrypted images. I even tried setting myself as the owner of them. Is the key stored in the $Windows.~BT folder that is created?

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: did you check the box to propagate the permissions into the child objects? sometimes you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: Wait, I just remembered. I had the images encrypted using the default windows security thing (when you right click and go to properties and encrypt them) on Windows 7 before I upgraded Windows. Is there a way to decrypt them or fix this?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @PJMahoney, i don't think same password theory would work here as the passwords are salted and they would be salted differently everytime

Comment: Windows during the upgrade created a **$Windows.~BT** folder and it was around 9GB, could it be stored somewhere in there?

Comment: Perhaps you could downgrade and back up the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the EFS Key. I searched for all files with the file extension .pfx on my hard drive, and since I only updated Windows, there was still a backup of the key.

Biggest sigh of relief.